# How do I add system versioning to this table definition with clause?

Tags: sql-server

I have the below table definition and I want to add system versioning to it but I can't seem to get it into the `WITH` clause without SQL Server complaining.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SysStartTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [SysEndTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here's the system versioning `WITH` clause.

`WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE=[dbo].[EmployeeHistory], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=ON));`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest and most succinct to create your table and then add the required system versioning elements:

```
create table [dbo].[Employee](
  [EmployeeId] [int] identity(1,1) not null,
  [FirstName] [varchar](50) null,
  [LastName] [varchar](50) null
constraint [PK_Employee_1] primary key clustered 
(
  [EmployeeId] asc
)with (pad_index = off, statistics_norecompute = off, ignore_dup_key = off, allow_row_locks = on, allow_page_locks = on) on [PRIMARY]
) on [PRIMARY]

alter table dbo.Employee add
    SysStartTime datetime2 generated always as row start constraint DF_EmployeeSysStart default SysUtcDateTime(),
    SysEndTime datetime2 generated always as row end constraint DF_EmployeeSysEnd default Convert(datetime2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
period for system_time (SysStartTime,SysEndTime);

alter table Employee set (system_versioning = on (history_table = dbo.EmployeeHistory, data_consistency_check=on));
```

Edit

To combine in a single `create table`

```
create table [dbo].[Employee](
  [EmployeeId] [int] identity(1,1) not null,
  [FirstName] [varchar](50) null,
  [LastName] [varchar](50) null,
    [SysStartTime] datetime2 generated always as row start constraint DF_EmployeeSysStart default SysUtcDateTime(),
    [SysEndTime] datetime2 generated always as row end hidden constraint DF_EmployeeSysEnd default Convert(datetime2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'),
    period for system_time (SysStartTime,SysEndTime),
    constraint [PK_Employee_1] primary key clustered ( [EmployeeId] asc) with (pad_index = off, statistics_norecompute = off, ignore_dup_key = off, allow_row_locks = on, allow_page_locks = on)
) with ( system_versioning = on (history_table = dbo.EmployeeHistory, data_consistency_check=on))
```

Comment: I'm trying to add this to the table definition in a DB project in Visual Studio. The `alter table` statement where `system_versioning` is set to on gives the error: "This statement is not recognized in this context".

Comment: @Legion Ah ok I think I see your issue, I have made an edit above. I think you've been trying to add the system version to the `with` for the primary key index options - it goes on its own. There is in fact no need for the `with(index options)` as they are all the default settings.

Comment: As soon as I put `system_versioning` in a `with` clause visual studio complains.

Comment: The create table I added above works fine when I run it on sql 2016 & 2019 - see here [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=444496d455825f13e6904fa638c336ac)